# Serializing an object which contains a list of other objects

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

**Background**: I am implementing a game which needs to serialize model objects (events) to be able to send them over the network to clients playing the game.

**Problem**: One of my model classes is `EventShowCards`, which subclasses `Event` (declared to be serializable).

```
public class EventShowCards extends Event {
    private final Player player;
    private final List<ItemCard> cards;

    public EventShowCards(Player player, List<ItemCard> cards) {
        super();
        this.player = player;
        this.cards = cards;
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public List<ItemCard> getCards() {
        return cards;
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Visitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

However, when I serialize the object and send it to the client, the client receives the object and list of `ItemCard`s is empty. **No exceptions are thrown**.

Event as shown by the server (before serialization):

[image]

Event as shown by the client (after serialization):

[image]

In order to serialize/deserialize I am using a standard ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream

Anyone has any idea of what could be happening here? Thanks.

**EDIT**

As request I am posting the code of the ItemCard (and Card):

*ItemCard.java*

```
public abstract class ItemCard extends Card {

    /**
     * By default a card ca be played independently from the game state, subclasses that have more complicated rules
     * must override this method.
     */
    public boolean canBePlayed(GameStateTurn gameState) {
        return true;
    }

    protected void emitEventCardPlayed(Player cardPlayer, GameState gameState)  {
        notifyObservers(new EventCardPlayed(cardPlayer, this));
    }

}
```

*Card.java*

```
public abstract class Card extends ConcreteObservable<Event> implements CardBehavior, Serializable {
    protected Deck<? extends Card> deck; // The deck to which this card belongs

    public Card() {
        super();
    }

    public void setDeck(Deck<? extends Card> deck) {
        this.deck = deck;
    }

    public void discard() {
        deck.discard(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void preEffect(Player cardPlayer, GameState gameState) {
        // By default cards have no preEffects
    }

    @Override
    public void postEffect(Player cardPlayer, GameState gameState) {
        // By default after a card is played it is discarded
        discard();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
        return cardNameFromClassName(className);
    }

    private String cardNameFromClassName(String className) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Character c: className.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                sb.append(" ").append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
            } else {
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }
        return "\"" + sb.substring(1) + "\"";
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

And Deck.java

```
public class Deck<T extends Card>
        extends ConcreteObservable<Event>
        implements Observer<Event>, Serializable {...}
```

**EDIT 3**

The List of item cards used to initialize the EventShowCards was an already created list from another model object of my application, passed as-is. Creating another ArrayList (copying that object) somehow solved my problem.

Comment: Are the LIste elements serializable? Do they implement the interface Serializable?

Comment: Yes, Card is serializable

Answer (score 1):

The List can contain unlimited number of object types.
As you have your `EventShowCards` serialized (through `Event` class), you need also to force your `ItemCard`class to be serializable in order to be marshalled and unmarshalled when needed correctly.

### EDIT

`java.util.List` doesn't implement Serializable, this is why your list is not serialized.
use other collections which are serializable like `ArrayList`

Comment: Fact is that my ItemCard object declares itself to be serializable (public abstract class ItemCard extends Card implements Serializable {...})... do I have to do anything else besides this?

Comment: java.util.List doesn't implement Serializable, this is why your list not serialized

Comment: The underling type used in this particular case is an ArrayList which implements Serializable

Comment: but it is declared as list, change it and try again

Comment: I think you are wrong... Another object that I am serializing this way has a Map<Obj1, Obj2> field and gets serialized just fine... Map is not serializable (like List), but the actual type of the object used (HashMap) is. In fact that object gets serialized just fine.

Comment: For the sake of argument I tried your suggestion and nothing changed as expected

Comment: I added the code for ItemCard and Card. Thank you for your time

Comment: is Deck serializable?

Comment: Yes also Deck is serializable (posted above)... however it has two fields which uses generics... could this be the problem?

Comment: you need to make your generic classes serializable as well

Comment: The generics are declared to be subclasses of Card, which implements serializable...

Comment: Great to hear that your problem is solved [PLUS ONE]